# How to use the array.length property to access and print to screen an item in an array

Tags: javascript

I am just starting to learn javascript and came across this scenario:

```
var namesArray = ["Steve", "John", "Betty", "Morty", "Rick", "Alan", "Sarah"]
```

I am trying to print to screen (with console.log) "Sarah" using namesArray while using the `array.length` property.

I have tried different ways and searched on google but to no avail.

I can resolve the issue using `nameArray[6]`, but I'm totally lost when it comes to arriving at the same solution using the array.length property.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: So you know you can print things with `console.log` – is the result of `console.log(namesArray.length)` any help?

Comment: Do you mean something lke `namesArray[namesArray.length - 1]` to access the last element in the array?

Comment: namesArray.length gives number of items in the array. Last index of array will be (namesArray.length - 1). Indexing of array starts from 0.

Comment: Have you tried `Array.find(...)`?

Comment: Hey thanks guys, eventually figured it out.

Comment: var namesArray = ["Steve", "John", "Betty", "Morty", "Rick", "Alan", "Sarah"];
var lastItemInArray = namesArray[namesArray.length - 1];

console.log(lastItemInArray);

Answer (score 1):

Since array index starts from 0, you should use `namesArray.length - 1` to access the last item.

```js
var namesArray = ["Steve", "John", "Betty", "Morty", "Rick", "Alan", "Sarah"];

var arrLen = namesArray.length;
var lastIndex = arrLen - 1; // Array index starts from 0, deduct 1
var lastPerson = namesArray[lastIndex];
console.log(lastPerson);
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he's asking about, but hey that works, so upvote from me

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for responding. I think I eventually figured it out. I used the following: var namesArray = ["Steve", "John", "Betty", "Morty", "Rick", "Alan", "Sarah"];
var lastItemInArray = namesArray[namesArray.length - 1];

console.log(lastItemInArray);  - this appeared to have worked which is similar to your code Mamun (well sort of). Thanks anyway guys.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `array.length` property to find the specific location of an index. You can, however, search for the index of a string if it is contained within a list, like so:

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var a = fruits.indexOf("Apple");
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response, eventually figured it out. Your way seems to be a different method and I take it on board. Thanks.